# How can I drop explicit 0's from tf.SparseTensor?

Tags: python, tensorflow, sparse-matrix

In each epoch of my model training, a `tf.SparseTensor` changes its values to have more explicit zeros. Removing such explicit zeros would make the number of explicit edges small, hence makeing the whole computation be faster.

So, I need a way to drop explicit zeros from `tf.SparseTensor` to make it more "slim". Does anyone know a way to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can solve this problem using the [`tf.sparse_retain()`](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/master/api_docs/python/tf/sparse_retain) op:

```
st = ...  # A `tf.SparseTensor` object.

# Compute a vector of booleans indicating which values of `st` should be dropped
# (if False) or retained (if True)
is_nonzero = tf.not_equal(st.values, 0)

# `tf.sparse_retain()` computes a new `tf.SparseTensor` with the specified values
# retained in the output.
st_without_zeros = tf.sparse_retain(st, is_nonzero)
```